# CS-Cart mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Class 'phpmailer' not found in ...app/Tygh/Mailer.php

Tags: php, phpmailer, cs-cart

I have a `cs cart` installation which used to work without any problems. But I just found that there is a problem right now, customers cant complete orders , they get back `500 error` page. In the error log I see this error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'phpmailer' not found in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/public_html/app/Tygh/Mailer.php on line 18, referer: https://example.com/index.php?dispatch=checkout.checkout
```

here is the code with the error in `Tygh/Mailer.php`:

```
namespace Tygh;

class Mailer extends \phpmailer
{ //ln:18
    private static $_mailer;
.......
```

Why I get this error? How I can fix it? In the settings page I have

> Method of sending e-mails: via php mail function

Answer (score 0):

If they are using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and not just something with the same name, that's simply broken code.

PHP is case sensitive for class names, and the current release of PHPMailer uses a namespace of `PHPMailer\PHPMailer`, so `\phpmailer` fails on two counts. I recommend reporting this to the creators of cs cart as it's their error to fix, and tell them to read [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading).

Comment: I changed it to PHPMailer\PHPMailer but I still get 500 error

Comment: The *namespace* is `PHPMailer\PHPMailer`, but the *fully-qualified class name* is then `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer` (yes, 3 of them, read the docs for why).

Comment: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tygh\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer' not found in

Comment: but this is the standard in cs cart setups... I dont know why its stopped suddenly... https://github.com/TimvanSteenbergen/Underfashion-with-CS-cart/blob/master/app/Tygh/Mailer.php

Comment: Like I said, it's a problem for cs cart to fix. The code you linked to has not been touched in 6 years. I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

why example.com? Better change mail settings to smtp. Or install addon cart power "mail delay" and have no errot, but its not fix no mail working.